# Prove that a certain sum of binomial coefficients is divisible by a power of 2

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, fibonacci-numbers

As many will recognize the following expression is a closed form for the Fibonacci numbers. Can it be proved that
$$\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n}{2j+1} 5^{j} \quad \text{where} \quad n \in\mathbb{N}$$
are integers without using the fact that these are the Fibonacci numbers?

Comment: Why downvote? It is not an interesting question? It is trivial? It is not stated properly? Ok, just say, please.

Comment: Don't pay attention to downvotes. Your question is indeed interesting.

Comment: The title is weird. _Every_ sum of odd binomial coefficients (with integer entries) is an integer. Indeed every sum of binomial coefficients (with integer entries) is an integer, as is every sum of odd numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Adding an upvote; the two downvotes are ludicrous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By binomial theorem the expression is equivalent to:
$$
S_n=\frac1 {2^{n}}\frac{(1+x)^n-(1-x)^n}x,
$$
where $x=\sqrt5$. Since the latter fraction which we denote $Z_n (x)$ is clearly integer ($x $ cancels leaving in the numerator only even powers of $x $), we need only to prove that it  is divisible by $2^{n}$.
To prove this we proceed as follows:
$$
2 Z_n (x)=[(1+x)+(1-x)]Z_n (x)=Z_{n+1}(x)+(1-x^2)Z_{n-1}(x)\tag1
$$

Dividing (1) by $2^{n+1} $ and rearranging terms one obtains:
$$
S_{n+1}=S_n+\frac {x^2-1}4S_{n-1}\tag2
$$

Since $S_0=0$ and $S_1=1$ the statement $S_n\in\mathbb Z$ follows by induction for all $n\ge0 $ provided that $4|(x^2-1) $ which is indeed true.

Comment: After reading this answer I realize that a better question to ask would be: Let $y\in\mathbb{N}.$ Prove that $y \equiv 1 \, (\operatorname{mod} 4)$ if and only if $2^n\bigl|\bigr. \bigl((1+\sqrt{y})^n-(1-\sqrt{y})^n\bigr)/\sqrt{y}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Or, equivalently, $\displaystyle 2^{n-1}\Biggl|\Biggr.\sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n}{2j+1} y^{j}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: I think your question was stated absolutely correct. Without knowing the answer it is hard to guess which condition may be decisive.

Comment: Thank you very much for a nice solution!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$S_n=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n}{2j+1} 5^{j} \quad \text{where} \quad n \in\mathbb{N}$$

By binomial theorem $$2\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}{n\choose 2k+1} (\sqrt{5})^{2k}=(1+x)^n-(1+x)^n$$
$$S_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}[(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n-(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^n]=F_n$$
Where $F_n$ is Fibonacci number which is always a positive integer. Moreover, one may also check that $S_0=F_0=0$
and $S_1=1=F_1$.

Comment: Yes, you recognized it. But, can this be proved without going back to Fibonacci numbers? Isn't that an interesting combinatorial exercise?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$S_n=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor} \binom{n}{2j+1} (\sqrt{5})^{2j} \quad \text{where} \quad n \in\mathbb{N}$$
Use ${n \choose k}={n-1 \choose k}+{n-1 \choose k-1}$
$$\implies S_n=2^{n-1} \sum_{j=0}^{[n/2]}\left({n-1 \choose 2j} (\sqrt{5})^{2j}+{n-1 \choose 2j-1} \sqrt{5}^{2j}\right)$$
Next, these two parts can yield $S_n=S_{n-2}+S_{n-1}$ sfter interesting adjustments.

I hope to come back.